# Should an observable emitted by a data service return a sequence of objects or an array of objects?

Tags: angular, rxjs

Trying to learn Angular and RxJS and I'm a bit confused about what a data service should return. A sequence of objects or an array of objects? What's the best practice?

```
import { from, of  } from 'rxjs';
import {map, toArray} from 'rxjs/operators';

const items = [
    {id: 1, name: "foo"},
    {id: 2, name: "bar"}
];

// "Standard" map behaviour going throuch each item of the array
const names = items.map( item => item );
```

**Version 1:**
to have the equivalent of `Array.prototype.map()` with RxJS `map` I'd work with a sequence of objects:

```
// I can go directly through the items using map and then use toArray()
const version1 = from(items).pipe(
  map(item => item),
  toArray(),
).subscribe(
  name => console.log('version1', item)
);
```

**Version 2:**
To do the same with an Observable emitting an array of objects:

```
const version2 = of(items).pipe(
    map(items => items.map( item => item)) // weird nested mapping
).subscribe(
  item => console.log('version2', item)     
);
```

Version 2 looks weird since I have to do a "nested" map just to go through my items.

Since Angular `HttpClient get()` method does return an array of objects, I should go for version 2, but it does not feel "natural" to work with. In any case, I have to end up with an array of objects...

So, version 1 or version 2?

Comment: Angular HttpClient doesn't return anything. Your back end is returning things. If you need an array of things, return an array. If you need individual items, return individual items.

Comment: The question is not about HttpClient but about the idiomatic way to work with Observables emitting items. Does it make more sense to work with individual items and make an array of it when needed or directly with an array of items. It might matter for more advanced use case, I don't know...

Comment: But that's what I'm saying, it depends on what you need. At any given point in time, do you need an array of items, or one item? What you need is what you should emit. If at one point you will use an array, and moments later you want to use a modified array, you need to emit arrays. Observables are not arrays, they are elements in time. If without observable you have `string[]` then you should emit `Observable<string[]>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it depends on how the data is consumed. Version 2 is the correct way to think about this **if the data you are trying to expose through the service is conceptually an array of items**.

Think of it this way, if you had an service which were to fetch a 2d array (lets say `string[][])` containing data to be displayed in a 2d grid in a user interface, then it would make sense to expose it via an Observable which emits a single `string[][]`, not a sequence of `string`, as it would make the data difficult to consume.

The nested mapping may look different to what you are used to, but most people who work with RxJS regularly would not say that this is 'weird'. In my opinion it is in no way unreadable, and is very declarative. It instantly says to me that you are applying a transformation to an array which has been emitted by an Observable.